# jCarousellite not displaying in IE 6/7/8, fine in Safari/FF/Chrome

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to implement a slideshow like this one: http://biggayicecreamtruck.com but for the life of me I can't figure out why their code works and mine doesn't. My page is here: http://oaxacankitchenmobile.com. It's not that IE isn't styling it, the images just aren't showing up at all. Like I said, the slideshow works fine in FF/Safari/Chrome. Here's my code on the main page

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <ul>
            <li><img title="Picture 1" alt="Picture 1" src="images/slideshow1.jpg" />
                <div class="text-bg"></div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h2>La Flor de Pi&ntilde;a</h2>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><img title="Picture 2" alt="Picture 2" src="images/slideshow2.jpg" />
                <div class="text-bg"></div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h2>Agua Frescas</h2>
                </div>
            </li>
                            ...and so on...
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with the way I'm listing the images, since it's exactly the same as the other site. jQuery is loading fine, since it works on those other browsers. I'm assuming that I'm initializing the code correctly again, since it works on other browsers. The jCarousellite code I'm using is exactly the same as the one from the other site.

I'm thinking that my problem has to be with my CSS, but there's where I'm stuck. I can't figure out what I need to change to get the slide show to appear at all in IE. Can anyone help me? Here's the relevant CSS:

```
/*SLIDESHOW*/
#slideshow                          { width: 900px; height: 350px; border: 1px solid #362626; display: none; margin: 0 auto 28px; }
    #slideshow ul                   { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; }
    #slideshow img                  { width: 900px; height: 350px; }
    #slideshow li                   { width: 900px; height: 350px; position: relative; }
    #slideshow .text-bg             { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 900px; height: 58px; background-color: #000; }
    #slideshow .text                { position: absolute; bottom: 18px; left: 18px; width: 900px; text-align: left; }
    #slideshow h2                   { display: inline; font-size: 18px; line-height: 24px; color: white; font-family: "Baskerville Old Face", serif; }
    #slideshow h2 a:hover           { text-decoration: none; }
    #slideshow p                    { display: inline; font-size: 13px; margin-left: 7px; }
```

One other bit adding to my frustration: my jQuery .load calls aren't working on this page, either. So, it appears that no jQuery scripts are working on this page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A problem, perhaps *the problem* is on Line 75 in `/js/okm.js`:

```
$('#slideshow').jCarouselLite({
    visible: 1,
    speed: 800,             
    auto: 4000,
    vertical: false,
    pauseOnHover: true, //<---
});
```

Remove that extra comma - [it breaks IE](https://web.archive.org/web/20120308162403/http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2010/12/19/beware-the-trailing-comma-of-death/):

```
pauseOnHover: true
```

[image]

Comment: dear god. this is one i won't overlook again. 6 hours later... THANK YOU!!! any ideas about the failed jquery load calls?

Comment: never mind. that comma apparently made my entire script not work. now it's all cool. !

Comment: Oh, good. I was just about to comment "they seem to be working now".

Comment: @thirtydot, just to let you know, I've "borrowed" your image for [a blog post](http://www.davidarno.org/2016/03/23/trailing-commas-good-or-bad-practice-tldr-its-bad/) and credited back to you here. Let me know if you don't want me to do this and I'll remove it.

Comment: @DavidArno: I don't mind, but it was never my image to begin with, it came from an article which no longer seems to exist. I actually use trailing commas, for all the usual reasons. In particular, because it means I can use the "duplicate line command" in my editor on the last line and I don't then have to add a comma to the previous line. Adding an item to the end of a list is quite common.

Answer (score 0):

If you find that image intriguing I would suggest running over to http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2010/12/19/beware-the-trailing-comma-of-death/ where it was originally posted :)

Comment: I did already link to that in my answer. See the link for: "it breaks IE".