# jCarousel Lite Not Working in IE 6/7/8

Tags: internet-explorer, jcarousellite

So I seem to be having the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891575/jcarousellite-not-displaying-in-ie-6-7-8-fine-in-safari-ff-chrome) fellow. My jCarousel doesn't seem to be working in IE, the images just don't show up. Anyone know what the problem could be? I don't seem to have a Trailing Comma of Death...

Here's a [link](http://zakopanerentals.com/raph/) to my site.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you coded into the div a

```
style="opacity:0;"
```

or some opacity of zero, remove it.